# Handle multiple dropdown lists with VueJS

Tags: vue.js, event-handling, counter, dropdown

I am new at VueJs and I want to create a form. It contains questions with category and rate. My target is to take the rate of each question and his category, and all questions from category 'F' will have scoreF (which will occur from the sum of rates) and all questions from category 'H' will have a scoreH. Here is my job till now. Thank you in advance for your help!

https://codepen.io/dparanou/pen/zYGPexa

```
<select v-bind:id="question.id" @change="onChange($event, question.id, question.category)">
 <option disabled selected>--</option>
 <option v-for="n in question.answers" :value="n">{{n}}</option>
</select>

<span>Score F: {{fScore}}</span>
<span>Score H: {{hScore}}</span>
```

And here is my JS file

```
data: {
    fScore: 0,
    hScore: 0,
},
methods: {
    onChange(event, id, cat) {
      num = event.target.value;
      console.log("id: "+ id + ", category: " + cat + ", score: " + num);
      if(cat == "F") {
        this.fScore += num;
        console.log(this.fScore);
      } else {
        this.hScore += num;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It had only to convert the event into Integer!

```
onChange(event, id, cat) {
      var num = parseInt(event.target.value);
      if(cat == "F") {
        this.fScore += num;
      } else {
        this.hScore += num;
      }
    }
```